# Filter in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, rendering, react-props

I'm trying to make a filter of all my "localtypes" but when I check the console on my browser it shows me an empty array. I want to get to the localtypes propertys of the API I'm using

I tried to use this filter

```
 const type = (category) => {
   const clonArray = [...restaurants]
   const filter = clonArray.filter((restaurant) => {
     return restaurant.localtype == category;
   })
   setRestaurants(filter);
  }
```

sending the props to another component "Filter" as

```
categories={() => type()}
```

but when i get to these props in the Filter component i get an empty array

```
onClick={() => {categories("farmacia")}}>
```

I want to know how to access to the props of "categories"

Comment: You’ve made categories a function which takes no parameters and calls type with no parameters.  Try `categories={(thing) => type(thing)}`

Comment: I've been trying for hours to figure out how to solve this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in below order. First thing to note is that `.filter` does not mutate the original array, so you can use it directly.

You need to pass the value with function to the Filter component.

```
onClick={() => categories('farmacia'}

categories={(cat) => type(cat)}

const type = (category) => {
   const filter = clonArray.filter((restaurant) => {
     return restaurant.localtype === category;
   })
   setRestaurants(filter);
}
```